# Doxygen warning: documented function not declared or defined

Tags: c++, warnings, doxygen

I'm trying to use Doxygen for the first time. On running Doxygen, I am presented with a large number of warnings of the following form:

<code>.cxx:<line number>: warning: documented function `<function>::<function>' was not declared or defined.

I'm not sure how to approach the problem. I'm working with a large C++ package and this type of warning is thrown up a few hundred times on running Doxygen.

Here's more specific information:

example warning:

```
            Accept.cxx:14: warning: documented function `Accept::Accept' was not declared or defined.
```

corresponding example section of code:

```
            #include "Analysis/Accept.h"
            #include "Analysis/Cutflow.h"
            #include "GlaNtp/GlaUtil/Steer/Steer.h"
            #include <iostream>

            Accept::Accept(unsigned int cutmask, unsigned int invertword, StringIntMap* CutTypeMap, Cutflow* analysis_cutflow): m_cutmask(cutmask), m_invertword(invertword), 
                                                                            m_cutword(0),m_cutword_set(false), m_CutTypeMap(CutTypeMap),
                                                                                    m_analysis_cutflow(analysis_cutflow){ 
                                                                                        // this is constructor
            InitBitOrder();

            }

            Accept::~Accept(){}

            void Accept::setCutWord(const unsigned int &cutword){
             m_cutword_set = true;
             m_cutword = cutword;
            }

            bool Accept::didBitPass(){
             //std::cout << "Rick Evnt Pass: " << rickTestCutWord() << std::endl;
             return testCutWord();
            }

            void Accept::InitBitOrder(){

             Steer* bitorsteer=new Steer(); 

             std::string configfile="ConFigFiles/ApplyBits/BitOrderConfigurationFile.txt";

            if(!bitorsteer->ReadFile(configfile)){
             std::cout << "Fatal ERROR: Failed to read Bit Order configuration steering file:  " << configfile << std::endl;
             delete bitorsteer;
             bitorsteer=0;
             exit(1);
            }

            m_bitOrderMap = new StringIntMap("BitOrder", bitorsteer);//  bit order

            delete bitorsteer;
            }
```

I would appreciate any assistance you might have in pointing me in the right direction.

Preemptive thanks

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that Doxygen is not parsing the `Analysis/Accept.h` header file, so it's not seeing the `Analysis` class declaration. In the output log, check that `Analysis/Accept.h` is indeed being processed.

To ensure that Doxygen parses the `Analysis` directory, you may have to add additional source directories in Expert->Input (in the Doxygen GUI frontend), and/or enable the Recursive option. Perhaps you have to specify a source directory one level above the one you've currently specified.

Comment: Thanks, enabling the recursive option did it for me, even though my source path contained all files I needed to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and followed the advice given by Emile Cormier.  In my case the relevant header file was indeed not being parsed.  This was because I have a c++ header file with the extension .h.  I originally had the following in my Doxygen.in file:

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = .h=C++
```

Looking at the output carefully, I noticed the statement: "Adding custom extension mapping: ..h will be treated as language c++", indicating an extra ".".  Removing the period from the relevant line fixed my problem.

Comment: As of v1.9.1, FILE_PATTERNS has already included .h so that this mapping would not be necessary any more.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had another case that triggered such a warning: having a typedef done in two different places.  This is OK wrt C++, but causes doxygen (1.8.7) to issue this very warning.  Reordering to have a single definition fixed it.

Comment: Adding to this, I had an issue where using a macro defined in another file caused doxygen 1.9.3 to ignore the file (a header file leading to this warning). Adding `/// \cond DO_NOT_DOCUMENT` around the call to the macro fixed the issue